# parameterized query........ unexpected in database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hello there I am trying to enter database records from `window Form` design and programmed using `MS visual C#` and it approved and entered database using an other `Window Form` and I call the child `Form` using `showDialog` , I tried to make it entering to and sending thde data using string array  and send it
as following

```
    public string[] cashg1
    {
        get { return dt; }
        set { dt = value; }
       }
          public void Entering(){
              form2.ShowDialog();
              string[] inputs = new string[10];
              DateTime Date = DateTime.Today;
              inputs[0] = numb.Text;
              inputs[1] = comboBox1.SelectedText;
              inputs[2] = owner.Text;
              inputs[3] = curency.Text;
              inputs[4] = curncyval.Text;
              inputs[5] = Depet.Text;
              inputs[6] = cridet.Text;
              inputs[7] = Convert.ToString(Date);
              inputs[8] = note.Text;

              form2.addingdata(inputs);
              cashg1 = inputs;
              }




            public void Entring_to database(){inputs = new string[10];
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            DateTime Date = DateTime.Today;
            try
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO   Accont(Account_ID,Account_Name,Owners,Curency,Curncytype,Depet,Credet_devet,Date,Note) VALUES ( @@AccountID, @AccountName, @Owner, @Curncy,@Curncytype,@Depet,@Cridetdevet,@Date,@Note)");
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@@AccountID", Convert.ToInt32(inputs[0]));
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputs[0]))
                    inputs[0] = "323";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountName", Convert.ToString(inputs[1]));
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputs[1]))
                    inputs[1] = "        ";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Owner", inputs[2]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Curncy", inputs[3]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Curncytype", inputs[4]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Depet", inputs[5]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cridetdevet", inputs[6]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", inputs[7]);
                connection.Open();//Owner
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error  :" + ee.Message);
            }
        }
      }
     }
```

I enter my data using this `Form`:
[image]
when I clicked conforming button to enter the data in `datagridview`
[image]
After conforming the data must enter the database but It dosenot enter and gives my this error

[image: Parmeterized Query Error]

thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddWithValue` will not add parameter, if value is null.

If setting AccountName to blank instead of null is intended, then you should change order of these strings in your code (i.e. you should initialize inputs[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if it is empty **before** adding this parameter, not after)

**Your code**

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountName", Convert.ToString(inputs[1]));
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputs[1]))
  inputs[1] = "        ";
```

**Should looks like**

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputs[1]))
  inputs[1] = "        ";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountName", Convert.ToString(inputs[1]));
```

Instead, if null should be inserted in database if inputs[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is empty, you should use `DBNull.Value`

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountName", inputs[1] == null ? DBNull.Value : Convert.ToString(inputs[1]));
```

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reference.